# Get form data (including concealed values) via API?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on a Form that contains various fields for adding values (texttabs/ listtabs/ etc).

The form goes to two recipients, one of whom has access to half the fields which have been set to "concealed" (true) to prevent other  recipients from viewing personal information.

**My question is**, is it possible to retrieve the Form Data (concealed values) via API? I'd like to reattach these concealed values to the final product in my API script once the form is completed in Docusign. I searched everywhere but could not find an answer.

Thanks,
    Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible to do through the DocuSign REST API.  It's not very intuitive but there's an API call you can make to retrieve the recipient entered values.

Have a look at the **Get Envelope Recipient Status** API call, and more importantly, it's one optional parameter.  Details of the call are:

**URL:**
`/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients`

**HTTP Method:**
`GET`

**Parameters:** 
`The only required parameter is the envelope ID. If the optional query include_tabs is set to true, the tabs associated with the recipient are returned. If the optional query include_extended is set to true, the extended properties are returned.`

-Example (from documentation)-

```
GET https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients?include_tabs=true

X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

See the [REST API Guide page 192](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf#page=192) for more info on the call.

Comment: Ah, got it. I was already performing this API call in a function so it was easy to append the `?include_tabs=true` parameter. I wish there was a mechanism for retrieving the concealed values in the form as they would appear normally.

Thanks Ergin.